# How do I use a serial port as a source for Syslog?

Tags: serial-port, syslog

I'm trying to log another server's serial console port to a central syslog server, so I have connected a laptop running CentOS. I can read the port with `minicom` or even do something like `cat /dev/ttyS0 | logger` as a test, but the newlines aren't linefeeds and I'd like to run it as a daemon. I'm trying to do something like [Kiwi Harvester](http://www.kiwisyslog.com/help/harvester/index.html) ([download](http://www.kiwisyslog.com/downloads.aspx#free-products-utilities)) or a Lantronix box. The syslog [file input](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html) option seems to only work with regular files.

Is there a native way of reading the serial port from syslog (or some common utility to do so) or do I need to write a script to glue these together?

Thanks.

Comment: Err, why not just fix the returns? `tr '\r' '\n' < /dev/ttyS0 | logger ...`

Comment: play around with `stty`.  There are many options such as your ports parity, et. al. just google it.

Comment: @thrig Sure, I can do that, but ultimately I'm trying to get the data into syslog natively, if possible, or to use a complete utility. I can knock together a perl script to clean up the data and send it to the central syslog server but wanted to see if there was a way to do it with just syslog. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @jnbbender I'm not sure how that will add the serial port as a syslog source. I can communicate to the serial port but I'm not sure if there's a native way in syslog to receive data from the port or if I need to write something myself. Thank you, though.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood.